# What does an asterisk in the password field in the shadow Linux file mean?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

In the shadow file (`/etc/shadow`) and after reading its documentation, the password field says:

```
Password, 13 character encrypted. A blank entry (eg. ::) indicates a password is not required to log in (usually a bad idea), and a ``*'' entry (eg. :*:) indicates the account has been disabled.
```

But, what does exactly does this mean:

```
``*'' entry (eg. : * :) indicates the account has been disabled
```

Because in this case

```
root:*:17848:0:99999:7:::
```

I can keep using the root count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it means "the *account* has been disabled" really. What documentation are you referring to?

This is what `man 5 shadow` reads in Raspbian [emphasis mine]:

> If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of `crypt(3)`, for instance `!` or `*`, the user will not be able to use a **unix password** to log in (but the user may log in the system by **other means**).
>
> This field may be empty, in which case no passwords are required to authenticate as the specified login name. However, some applications which read the `/etc/shadow` file may decide not to permit any access at all if the password field is empty.
>
> A password field which starts with a exclamation mark means that the password is locked. The remaining characters on the line represent the password field before the password was locked.

`!` and `*` seem similar here. From `man 1 passwd`:

> `-l`, `--lock`
> Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a password by changing it to a value which matches no possible encrypted value (it adds a `!` at the beginning of the password).
>
> Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still be able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key). To disable the account, administrators should use `usermod --expiredate 1` (this set the account's expire date to Jan 2, 1970).
>
> Users with a locked password are not allowed to change their password.

So I would say it's the *password* that is locked/disabled, not the *account*. In my Raspbian, Debian, Kubuntu and OpenWrt machines system users and `root` have either sole `*` or sole `!` in the applicable `shadow` file. I can still run like `sudo -u root bash -l`.

Comment: An unrelated question. What does "5" in the `man 5 shadow` mean? I check the `man --help` and it does not have an option for "5".

Comment: @Sathesh https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3586/108618

Comment: means section.. ah.. makes sense